# Sum num inside array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

If i have array like this

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, -1],
[2, 4, 5, -1, 1]
```

before sum each array, the requirement must have 4 largest number inside each array, but if ther is no 4 largest number inside the array, every number inside the array will be sum. So, the answer will be like this

1. 3
2. 12

how can i do that? any help?

Comment: What do you need help with specifically? Did you start? Like iterate over the values? Show us your code.

Comment: Sorry, can't comprehend your explanation, what does "the requirement must have 4 largest number inside each array" mean? Largest number of the first? OF the sum? How did you obtain your result?

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array descending, take the top four items and add all values.

```js
function sumTop4(array) {
    return array
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .slice(0, 4)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

console.log(sumTop4([1, 2, 1, 0, -1])); //  4
console.log(sumTop4([2, 4, 5, -1, 1])); // 12
```